# И снова противоречивые союзы - "зачем", "как", "что"

Tags: морфология

Еще 3 противоречивых союза -  **зачем**, **как**, **что** - или может не союзы?

> 1.Несчастный друг, **зачем** не прежде явилась ты моим очам в те дни, **как** верил я надежде и  упоительным мечтам!

ЗАЧЕМ, нареч. вопрос. и относ. С какою целью, для чего. Скажи, зачем ты пришел? Зачем ему нужно так много денег?

ЗАЧЕМ, местоим. и союзн. С какой целью, для чего. Зачем пришёл? Узнай, зачем он приходил.

Лично я разницы между не вижу, так что, это вообще не союз?

**Как** - здесь выступает как местоименное  **когда** - Ей сделалось дурно, как услышала о взятии Нижнеозерной.
А **"когда"** в таком значении - это относительное наречие употребляется в качестве союзного слова в определительных придаточных предложениях, относящихся к имени существительному главного предложения, обычно обозначающему какой-либо отрезок времени(Я люблю ездить на Старицу — в те дни, когда дым из труб ложится на огороды и деревня пахнет мокрой соломой и холодными яблоками)

Выходит что опять не союз?

> 2.Нужды нет(имеется ввиду "неважно"), **что** он парадов не делает да с
>   полками на нас не ходит...

В интернете сказано

**Что** - союзное слово или союз (если не падает логическое ударение) употребляется в сложноподчинённых предложениях - Я знаю, что он уже был там.

А как понять падает ли на него это ударение? Если ударение на **что** не падает - значит союз?

Comment: Если начинаете вопрос с "еще",  дайте хоть ссылку на предыдущее...

Answer (score 1):

Из вопроса пока понял только про ударение. Понимать тут ничего не нужно. Если есть основания отнести к союзному слову (т.е. "что" является членом предложения: подлежащим или дополнением), то ударение очевидно на него падает. Вы это не можете не почувствовать. 
Сравните: "Я узнал, **что** (именно) случилось" и  "Я узнал, что случилось несчастье".

То же самое (ну или почти) с "зачем"

Остальное пока не понял. В чем вопросы-то там?

Comment: Нужды нет, что он парадов не делает да с полками на нас не ходит... вроде на **что** ударение не падает...только это не помогает

Comment: Почему же не помогает? Здесь что - союз.

Answer (score 1):

1.Несчастный друг, **зачем** не прежде явилась ты моим очам в те дни, **как** верил я надежде и упоительным мечтам!

**Зачем**-наречие, т.к. отвечает на вопрос наречия и является обстоятельством.

В те дни, **как** верил я ...- *как-*союз, обозначающий временные отношения между главным и придаточным предложениями. К нему нельзя поставить вопрос как? когда?, он не является членом предложения, следовательно, это служебная часть речи, союз. Здесь он заменяет **союз когда**.

**Когда** может быть **союзом** (Когда он пришёл домой, было поздно-придат. времени)и **союзным словом**-относительным наречием (Он любил приезжать в деревню в те дни, когда начиналась жатва- придат. местоим.-определительное).В придаточном времени, придаточном условия(Как же я могу хотеть вашей погибели,когда я люблю вас?) это **союз**, в местоимённо-определительном наречие, **союзное слово**, фразовое ударение не обязательно.Жатва начиналась когда?-когда. В придат. изъяснительном **наречие, союзное слово**, вот там ударение обязательно: Я знаю, когда он придёт.Придёт когда?- когда.

2.Нужды нет, что он парадов не делает да с полками на нас не ходит...Что-союз, т.к. не является членом предложения, это служебная часть речи, служащая для присоединения придаточного к главному.Ударение на него не падает.

Я знаю, **что** он здесь делает.-ударение на него падает, это дополнение,выраженное местоимением, союзное слово.

Answer (score 0):

Уважаемая Lisa, Вам будет трудно действительно успешно разобраться с этой темой без знания видов сложноподчиненных предложений.По структуре СПП можно разделить на две группы: местоименная связь главного и придаточного предложения (союзы как исключение) и  союзная связь главного и придаточного предложения (союзные слова как исключения).Также существует переходный тип придаточных с местоименно-союзной связью.

Отличие союзных слов от союзов. Союзные слова являются ЧЛЕНАМИ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ, в отличие от    союзов, которые выполняют только  СЛУЖЕБНУЮ РОЛЬ и членами  предложения быть не могут.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.Несчастный друг, зачем не прежде явилась ты моим очам в те дни, как верил я надежде и упоительным мечтам!

Во-первых, пропущена запятая **перед**  "в те дни" (без неё предложение коряво).

В  изданиях Пушкина она есть:

*Несчастный друг, зачем не прежде явилась ты моим очам, в те дни, как верил я надежде и упоительным мечтам!*

= почему ты появилась только сейчас, а не в те дни?..

Чем является "как" в  придаточном -- союзом или союзным словом?

Хотя "как" в придаточном и можно было бы заменить местоимениями "когда" или "в какие / в которые", считать "как" в этом предложении союзным словом, по-моему, оснований мало:  никакого вопроса к этому слову  в придаточном не задашь, членом предложения его не сделаешь.  *Верил (когда?) -- как???  Верил (в какие дни?) -- как???*

Более-менее корректный вопрос можно поставить только ко всему придаточному: *в те дни (в какие?) -- как верил я надежде...*

И потому "как" в этом предложении **(при запятой или запятой плюс тире после "в те дни")** я бы считал союзом.

====================

Но запятая (или же запятая плюс тире) после "в те дни" -- не во всех изданиях.

К примеру, в Нацкорпусе пунктуация такова:

*Несчастный друг, зачем не прежде явилась ты моим очам,*

*В те дни **как** верил я надежде и упоительным мечтам!*

= Ну почему же в годы моей молодости не удалось мне  встретить тебя? Ведь тогда я был совсем иным, тогда я был полон надежд и упоительных мечтаний! А сейчас...

При такой пунктуации "как" будет уже и не союзом, и не союзным словом.

По-моему,  усилительной **частицей**, обозначающей наивысший предел, высшую степень (такое значение "как" отмечено у Ефремовой: http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/172854 ). Хотя можно, наверное, считать и **наречием**. К примеру,  Бурцева в предложении  *"Как я рад вас видеть!"* видит наречие со значением "до какой степени".